# User Profile update with UpdateView with Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I extended User with a profile. Signup and login works fine, but I have a problem to implement a UserPofile (User + Profile models).
Form is rendered, but it's not stored. I'm out of ideas where to look now. What can be wrong? How to debug this?

Views:

```
class UserSettings(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'users/settings.html'
    context_object_name = 'user'
    model = UserProfile
    form_class = ProfileUpdateForm


    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('users:user-settings', kwargs={'pk': self.get_object().id})


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserSettings, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_form'] = UserUpdateForm(instance=self.object.user)
        return context
```

Model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    picture = models.ImageField(default='users/default_user.png', upload_to='users', blank=True, null=True)

def post_user_created_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)


post_save.connect(post_user_created_signal, sender=User)
```

Forms:

```
class UserUpdateForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = [
            'picture'
            ]
```